# Difference between /var/log/messages, /var/log/syslog, and /var/log/kern.log?

Tags: logging, syslog

For the purposes of kernel logging, why do I have three different, non-inclusive levels of logging amongst `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog`, and `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: Note that /var/log/messages is the syslog on non-Debian/non-Ubuntu systems such as RHEL or CentOS systems usually.

Comment: Note that `journalctl` is slowly replacing `syslog` as go to resource for monitoring system messages.

Comment: what about syslog and syslog.1 ? what is the difference...

Comment: @haytham-medhaytham you may find the "Log Rotation" section in this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Log_Rotation) helpful

Answer (score 82, accepted):

[Syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) is a standard logging facility. It collects messages of various programs and services including the kernel, and stores them, depending on setup, in a bunch of log files typically under `/var/log`. In some datacenter setups there are *hundreds* of devices each with its own log; **syslog** comes in handy here too. One just sets up a dedicated syslog server which collects all the individual device logs over the network. Syslog can also save logs to databases, and other clients.

According to my `/etc/syslog.conf`, default `/var/log/kern.log` captures only the kernel's messages of any loglevel; i.e. the output of `dmesg`.

`/var/log/messages` instead aims at storing valuable, non-debug and non-critical messages. This log should be considered the "general system activity" log.

`/var/log/syslog` in turn logs everything, except auth related messages.

Other insteresting standard logs managed by syslog are `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/mail.log`.

---

#### 2020 update

You may still stumble upon syslog; but the defaults have changed.

`journald` has replaced syslog, in quite a big portion of systems, including Ubuntu.

This is relevant because you won't be finding `/var/log/messages` that often anymore. `journald` doesn't write plaintext logs — it uses its own, compressed and partially authenticated format.

Search online for e.g. *journalctl cheatsheet*, or just study `man 8 systemd-journald`, `man 1 journalctl` yourself.

Syslog and journald are, to a degree, cross-compatible; you can transport logs between them in either direction. However, you won't get plaintext logs a-la `/var/log/messages` with journald; and you won't get structured (`journalctl -o json-pretty`) and authenticated logging with syslog.

Comment: any references to you claims please?

Comment: @Goaler444, `man syslog.conf`.

Comment: Note that entries in the kernel ring buffer (what dmesg reads) won't make it into any /var/log file by default if they were written by a user space process. You need to set `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` in rsyslogd's config if you want to see those messages in `/var/log`. See my answer at http://askubuntu.com/a/490900/297973 for more details.

Comment: also worth noting that ubuntu ([since natty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/794727)) no longer uses `/var/log/messages`, and stores everything on `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: in Ubuntu 16.04 `/var/log/syslog` is indeed a clean superset of `/var/log/kern.log` with the caveat that one has to account for different rotation strategies. E.g. in my system (default config unchanged) today's and yesterday's messages are kept in a single file in `/var/log/kern.log` whereas most of yesterday's messages for `syslog` are in `/var/log/syslog.1`.

Comment: Now see: `man rsyslog.conf`

Comment: On at least some systems `/var/log/messages` is where `dmesg` logs to FWIW... (Red Hat)

Answer (score 15):

- syslog contains all the messages except of type auth.
- messages contains only generic non-critical messages. The category is `info` , `notice` and `warn`
- For complete log look at `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/auth.log`
- AFAIK `/var/log/kern.log` contains kernel messages.
- log files are just a convention spelled out in /etc/syslog.conf
- read `syslog(3)` for more information

Check this page about [differences between messages and syslog](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20101007163324/http://namakajiri.net/complog/the-difference-between-messages-and-syslog/)

it says `/var/log/messages` [⊂](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: The link you provided is broken.

Comment: @slm [Here is the archived version](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20101007163324/http://namakajiri.net/complog/the-difference-between-messages-and-syslog/).

Comment: Duplicating the comment an ulidtko's answer:

also worth noting that ubuntu ([since natty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/794727)) no longer uses `/var/log/messages`, and stores everything on `/var/log/syslog`