# In 10.04 there is /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog

Tags: 10.04, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between /var/log/messages, /var/log/syslog, and /var/log/kern.log?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26237/difference-between-var-log-messages-var-log-syslog-and-var-log-kern-log)

Both these files are present in ubuntu 10.04 yet they seem to contain different information. What's the difference between these two files?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26237/difference-between-var-log-messages-var-log-syslog-and-var-log-kern-log).

/etc/syslog.conf defines the difference between the files.  You can look at that file to see what logs where, and to change what logs where.

Answer (score 0):

Differences of versions between 10.04 and 10.10

The /var/log/messages only exists until 10.10. This file contains more generic messages, while The /var/log/syslog is generated by the system logging daemon (syslogd).

I guess others also raised the question and so the  /var/log/messages got removed.