# Ubuntu 14.04.3 has frozen. What logs to check after reboot?

Tags: 14.04, logs

My HP Probook 6470b runs Ubuntu 14.04.3 with default open intel graphic driver and proprietary *bcmwl-kernel-source* for BCM43228 wifi. It froze after I had turned wifi off and would not react on a pressed key so I coult not reach terminal with ctrl-shft-F1. Chrome was open.

How can I check what went wrong after I did hard reboot? What logs and commands should I check to find out a clue what has failed? Could *dmesg* survive reboot?

After a hard reboot it runs fine again. I know the time of a failure so I could perhaps find some errors in kernel logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `/var/log/syslog` . It logs everything with respect to time. You can check the logs for the time when your system froze .

For details you might want to see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26237/difference-between-var-log-messages-var-log-syslog-and-var-log-kern-log)
.

Comment: How long does this file save logs in history?