# Black screen shows off suddenly after 2 - 4 hours

Tags: 16.04, screen, mate

After **2 - 4 hours** my laptops starts showing me a black screen when I click somewhere. This has happened many times, and it happens only when my laptop is awake for a long time and a lots of tabs are open. (Firefox and multiple terminals in diverse workspaces) I do suspend it for 5 or 10 minutes by closing its lid. This problem happens more when multiple terminals are open.
**Also fans of the laptop makes so much loud**

**Machine info:**

- Acer Aspire 5742
- Intel Core i3-370M
- 4 GB ram
- Intel HD graphics
- Triple boot (**Ubuntu Mate 16.04**, CentOS 7, Windows 7)

The time has reduced to one-half to one hour.  It is getting worse, I can't do any work.  Is it a hardware or software problem?

I posted it [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/black-screen-shows-off-suddenly-after-2-4-hours/13615/2) too.

Also now it is getting worst and it shows me black screen after 15 or 20 minutes.I have found so many logs in `/var/log` which mentions time when black screen shows off,but they are too many i didn't understand them.I don't think that it my screen problem as when black screen shows off,The song in my headphone Also stops playing!!

#### edit 22 July

I am using Linux mint XFCE 18.2(which is in other words is Xubutnu) and I am not getting this problem.I am using Linux mint XFCE. since one month.Also I was not getting this problem in Ubuntu unity.Thus I think that this is not my hardware problem but is related to Ubuntu mate.

Comment: Can you find any related information in the logs in `/var/log`?

Comment: @Melebius thanks for reply,but please tell me what are these logs? some people on ubutnu-mate-comutiny had also asked the same.but i am noob in Linux

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/26237/difference-between-var-log-messages-var-log-syslog-and-var-log-kern-log, for example.

Comment: i will provide logs when it will happen again

Comment: @Melebius Sorry but i am unable to find info in logs

Comment: Disable lockscreen, set all the Display power management settings to Never (I'm on Xubuntu so things may be called differently). Then see if the problem returns.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suspect an overheating issue, especially if it is getting worse over time.  Your comment that the fans get loud indicate that either the bearings are wearing out or that they are PWM fans and are reacting to the high internal heat by speeding up.  This does not sound like a kernel version or a RAM issue to me although high heat can certainly adversely effect performance and stability.

More windows open means more work for the CPU and perhaps GPU to do.  And thus, more heat generated.

Could be a clogged filter, clogged air inlet, a dead fan and so on.  Or that you are just running more processes than your laptop is capable of handling.

A quick test to validate this theory would be to take the laptop some place cool, such as outside.

Overheating to the point of shutting down every 2-4 hours will make it difficult to test for improvements.  Failing every 30 minutes, not so difficult.

When in a suspended state, the inside of the laptop case will eventually cool down because not much will be running.

You can install psensor which will monitor temps and discovered fans.  Alerts can be displayed based on thresholds that you specify.  There are several very good threads on this site explaining how to do this.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto

Comment: how can i install psensor??

Comment: I don't think that it is overheating problem as its winter here and my laptops shows me black screen again when I just opened it,It pretty cool at that time.

Comment: "how can i install psensor??"... `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get psensor` will do the needful.

Answer (score 2):

Start by installing newer kernel and Xorg versions:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

After that, try installing the latest Mesa version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If you still have issues, it is probably a hardware problem (Acers=ugh.  In the future, by a Dell or Toshiba)  Try using Memtest86+ (one of the options in the Grub screen) and let the test run for a few hours.

Comment: I installed new kernel,and problem was not occurring until last 5 days,but now suddenly it is showing up again!!!! the new kernel is  `4.10.0-22-generic`

Comment: Have you tried Memtest86+ yet?

Comment: No.I don't even know what is it?Can you please tell me what it is and how can i try it out?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86

Comment: i ran memtest86+ and no errors were found.

Comment: What is the output of `apt show libgl1-mesa-glx`?

Comment: I have edited my question with the output of the command   `apt show libgl1-mesa-glx`

Comment: It seems you did not run the second set of commands from answer, try those.

Comment: I tried all commands lets see if black screen shows off again?