# WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap in /var/log/syslog

Tags: log, syslog

My /var/log/syslog is completly full of the following warning:-

```
WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap
```

I am pasting some last lines of my /var/log/syslog

```
 Jul  1 14:52:46 smit-Aspire-5742 com.canonical.indicator.application[1762]: (process:2054): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Application already exists, re-requesting properties.
 Jul  1 14:52:46 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.ClockAppletFactory[1762]: (clock-applet:2002): MateWeather-CRITICAL **: weather_info_abort: assertion 'info != NULL' failed
 Jul  1 14:52:46 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.ClockAppletFactory[1762]: (clock-applet:2002): MateWeather-CRITICAL **: _weather_info_fill: assertion '((info == NULL) && (location != NULL)) || ((info != NULL) && (location == NULL))' failed
 Jul  1 14:52:46 smit-Aspire-5742 whoopsie[1051]: [14:52:46] online
 Jul  1 14:52:47 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.ClockAppletFactory[1762]: (clock-applet:2002): MateWeather-CRITICAL **: weather_info_abort: assertion 'info != NULL' failed
 Jul  1 14:52:47 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.ClockAppletFactory[1762]: (clock-applet:2002): MateWeather-CRITICAL **: _weather_info_fill: assertion '((info == NULL) && (location != NULL)) || ((info != NULL) && (location == NULL))' failed
 Jul  1 14:52:48 smit-Aspire-5742 ntpd[1494]: Listen normally on 9 wlp2s0 192.168.1.3:123
 Jul  1 14:52:48 smit-Aspire-5742 ntpd[1494]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
 Jul  1 14:53:05 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16801462,1113,0
 Jul  1 14:53:05 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16801594,1113,0
 Jul  1 14:53:05 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16801615,1113,0
 Jul  1 14:54:42 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.BrightnessAppletFactory[1762]: ** (mate-brightness-applet:2000): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16801677,1179,0
 Jul  1 14:54:43 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.BrightnessAppletFactory[1762]: ** (mate-brightness-applet:2000): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16801773,1179,0
 Jul  1 14:55:23 smit-Aspire-5742 com.ubuntu.OneConf[1762]: WARNING:oneconf.hosts:Error in loading other_hosts file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/smit/.cache/oneconf/6000f7a516194fa7890aa1cd7d94d021/other_hosts'
 Jul  1 14:58:02 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16802388,1113,0
 Jul  1 14:58:02 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16802390,1113,0
 Jul  1 14:58:02 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16802397,11,0
 Jul  1 14:58:02 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16802397,1113,0
 Jul  1 14:58:02 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16802418,11,0
 Jul  1 14:58:02 smit-Aspire-5742 org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[1762]: ** (wnck-applet:1829): WARNING **: Failed to get pixmap 16802418,1113,0
```

I had checked the /var/log/syslog of my fathers computer who is running linux mint 18.01 xfce and his log is completely different then my log and he even doesn't get this p[roblem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922705/black-screen-shows-off-suddenly-after-2-4-hours).

i had Also install pixmap by `sudo apt install pixmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this syslog entries are because of transparent panels and they have nothing to do with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922705/black-screen-shows-off-suddenly-after-2-4-hours) problem

Comment: Do you have a solution for the problem ?

Comment: @SorenA No.I dont have solution **yet**

Comment: Why do you then post an answer ?

Comment: @SorenA this is an answers for this question.the main problem is https://askubuntu.com/questions/922705/black-screen-shows-off-suddenly-after-2-4-hours

Comment: It's just that the wording "they have `nothing` to do with" that confuses me then.