# Random Black screen

Tags: display, intel-graphics, screen

I am facing random blank screen while using ubuntu flavors like mate or lubuntu. Suddenly out of blue screen goes black and force restart solves it. System is on its not overheating.

I searched many place but no clear solution.  So can you suggest me anything which can solve my issue.﻿

Regards
Kumar

Comment: Does your problem is like this??  https://askubuntu.com/questions/922705/black-screen-shows-off-suddenly-after-2-4-hours

Comment: Go to console by Ctrl+Atl+F1 and run `dmesg` command to display messages. There should be some info about what happened.

Comment: @SAMIT PATIL problem seems like what you stated even my laptop is Acer 5742..Only ubuntu derivative giving this issue